# Clojure: decide if argument is a prime

Tags: clojure

I started learning Clojure a few days ago and wrote a simple function that decides whether its given argument is a prime or not. 
Here is my code:

```
(defn is-prime [n] 
    (nil? 
        (some #(= (mod n %) 0) 
            (range 2 (java.lang.Math/sqrt n)))))
```

My problem is, that this function returns true when it is called with '4'.

(is-prime 4) => true

I wrote another function for debuggin purposes, it lists all the primes that are less than 250:

```
(defn primes [] (filter #(is-prime %) (range 1 250)))
```

I have looked up the Wikipedia page for the list of prime numbers and found that except for the number '4', the rest of the output is correct.

(primes)
=> (1 2 3 4 5 7 9 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 37 41 43 47 49 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 121 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 169 173 179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229 233 239 241)

I have been thinking about it, and maybe it is just some beginner's mistake on my part, but I'm unable to find the solution. I would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(range m n)` doesn't include n. So `(range 2 (sqrt 4)` = `(range 2 2)` = `()`; it doesn't try any divisors. Note your "primes" list also has 9 in it: `(range 2 (sqrt 9))` = `(range 2 3)` = `(2)` so it never tries dividing by 3. Same issue for 25, 49, 121, 169; basically for all squares of primes.

Simplest fix is `(range 2 (inc (sqrt n)))`.

Comment: I didn't notice the rest of the square numbers, thank you so much for the solution!